# Debugging Visual Studio 2010 Templates

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, poco

I'm using the visual studio POCO Template for the Entity Framework, so far it has worked great, but since my database/tables are not Upper Cammel Case, but UPPER case, every time that i need to regenerate the entities, i also need to (manually) change the entities on the edmx to be upper cammel case... which is really annoying

what i would like to do is to change the template to translate the Database tables and columns to upper cammel case E.G.

MY_TABLE_NAME => MyTableName

For that i need to understand how the template (tt file) works, and if possible debugg it to know where the change needs to be made.

Thanks!

Comment: You can make changes directly to template. It is just about understanding its code which is C# or VB with some control markup. You don't need any editor for simple changes - once you save the template VS will tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab a [T4 template editor from the visual studio gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5b0%5d.Type=SearchText&f%5b0%5d.Value=t4+editor&x=0&y=0).  Don't worry, they all suck in one way or another.

A T4 template is about as complex as an ASPX page without codebehind.  Its pretty simple to edit them.  As for debugging, I believe you have to spin up one instance of Visual Studio and debug it by attaching another instance.  Its a bit of a daunting task for someone without a lot of experience.

Depending on yours, the best thing might be to create a simple console application that has a single method to adjust your table names, then copypaste (please don't downvote me!) that method body into your T4 template.

Comment: Thanks man, i'm downloading the tool, i'll let you know the results!!

Comment: I'm downloading this tangible T4 Editor plus modeling tools for VS2010  (it was the most downloaded so far), but would you recomend one in specific?

Comment: @Bongo I'd skip that one because, personally, I have NEVER used any of the modeling T4 templates that get installed everywhere.  More annoying than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can include in the T4's C# code a call to

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

then when executed will "hit" the breakpoint, and ask to attach the debugger, attach Visual Studio (the 2nd Visual Studio will be debugging the first Visual Studio).